# robocopy - if a folder is excluded, but then removed from the source, it is removed from the destination also

Tags: robocopy

I have a robocopy script that uses /xd to exclude some folders in a /MIR copy which works well unless I delete the folder from the source - in which case it does not exclude the folder, it includes it and deletes it in the destination also!

How do I get around this one without having the directory in my source?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `/PURGE` or `/MIR`?

Answer (score 0):

The directory you do not want deleted in the mirror copy must be included in the exclusion list.

Comment: Yeah, it is in the exclusion list, but still gets deleted.